# BeautifulSoup4 Finding ahref

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<td valign="top"><a href="/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&amp;pageload=emne&amp;emneid=102981&amp;listview=1&amp;forhandlerid=21" class="list">Mercedes</a></td>
```

My code:

```
for link in soup.findAll('td',{'valign':'top'}):
    ahref = link.findAll('a',{'class':'list'})
    print(ahref)
```

But this does not give me back `href`.

Expected result:

```
href="/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&amp;pageload=emne&amp;emneid=102981&amp;listview=1&amp;forhandlerid=21"
```

How can I use `class="list"` to find that href?

Comment: You'll need to give us more details; I cannot reproduce any problems with your sample snippet of HTML (provided I wrap a `<table>` and `<tr>` element around it first).

Comment: Or are you asking how to extract just the value from the tag `href` attribute here? If so, at the very least update your question to include the expected outcome. I get that attribute with `soup.select('td[valign=top] a[href]')[0]['href']`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from you misunderstand of the `findAll` object. `href` is an attribute of a BeautifulSoup object and it can be accessed like a dictionary:

```
import bs4

raw = '''<td valign="top"><a href="/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&amp;pageload=emne&amp;emneid=102981&amp;listview=1&amp;forhandlerid=21" class="list">Mercedes</a></td>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw)

for td in soup.findAll('td',{'valign':'top'}):
    for link in td.findAll('a', {"class":"list"}):
        print (link["href"])
```

Results in

```
/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&pageload=emne&emneid=102981&listview=1&forhandlerid=21
```

Answer (score 0):

[`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) would do much better(and faster) job then BS4

```
from lxml import etree
q = etree.fromstring('<td valign="top"><a href="/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&amp;pageload=emne&amp;emneid=102981&amp;listview=1&amp;forhandlerid=21" class="list">Mercedes</a></td>')

print(q.find("a").attrib['href'] )
```

output:

```
/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&pageload=emne&emneid=102981&listview=1&forhandlerid=21
```

If you still insist on using `BS4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td valign="top"><a href="/default.asp?pagetemp=standard&amp;pageload=emne&amp;emneid=102981&amp;listview=1&amp;forhandlerid=21" class="list">Mercedes</a></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

output:

```
Found the URL: /default.asp?pagetemp=standard&pageload=emne&emneid=102981&listview=1&forhandlerid=21
```

Comment: "Much better" really depends on the input. As far as I understand, lxml only understands well-formed html, whereas Beautiful Soup is much more forgiving.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo you are correct `BS` is more forgiving, but in most of the cases `lxml` wont give you any trouble, also `lxml` provides a `soupparser`, in case you want parse the html like `BS`.